# Issue with React native d3 tree library

Tags: firebase, react-native, d3.js

I am currently using this library:
https://github.com/codesinghanoop?tab=overview&from=2017-05-01&to=2017-05-31

I am using react native and firebase is the backend. I want to be able to combine 2 or more family trees.  I am able to create one tree without problem but I am not able to link another tree to 1st tree.

Here is a screenshot:
[image: img]

Comment: Did you mean to link https://github.com/codesinghanoop/react-native-d3-tree-graph ?

Comment: Try adding some code, how are you trying to link trees?